# When to get Zed's Demise?

Tags: dead-island

What level should I get Zeds demise? Right now I am level 27 in Act 3 laboratory I just need to collect the blood from the tribe people. So what's a good level to get Zeds demise?

Answer (score 1):

The higher your level is when you get the weapon, the better it will be. Whether it's better to wait for a stronger version of it or to get it early is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to get it sooner rather than later because once you finish the story, you just start the story over again with the same character. You'll be able to get another (i.e. indefinitely more) Zed's Demise eventually.